# How can i get the path of files that i have choose in jfilechooser?

Tags: java, sockets, jfilechooser

In my program, I want to sent some files from client to server using socket programming. I'm using the `void setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean b)` method so I can choose more than 1 file, but it gives me an error when i try to get the path of the file.  Here's my code:

```
    JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();

    choose.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    choose.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png", "jpeg"));
    choose.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
    choose.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    File[] f = choose.getSelectedFiles();
    choose.showOpenDialog(this);

    String filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    String fname = f.getName();

    Client_ftp cli = new Client_ftp();
    if(cli.kirim(filePath, fname)) {
        jLabel1.setText("Success. .");
    } else {
        jLabel1.setText("failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

f is an array. You'll need to index the array before calling the getAbsolutePath() method for each File in f.  Make sure to check for null prior to doing so.

Example: f[0].getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Thank you.. it works, but it doesn't send any file that i have choose.